# How does HBase be used for storage?

Tags: hbase

As per my understanding, HBase stores its data in HDFS in the form of H-files.

How can if be used separately for storage?

where does it store all the data?

Answer (score 0):

```
As per my understanding, HBase stores its data in HDFS in the form of H-files
```

Your understanding is correct.

```
How can if be used separately for storage?
```

What do you mean by "separately"? You have to use some filesystem in order to use a DB(HBase, or whatever).

`Analogy :` When you store data in a MySQL table it eventually gets stored in the underlying FS(ext3, ext4 etc). Same holds true for HBase.

Storing data in a DB is nothing more than arranging your data in a sophisticated fashion, so that you can access it quickly(and randomly).

HBase has a pluggable architecture and can be used with any other supported system. In fact, you could go as far as implementing your own filesystem.

```
where does it store all the data?
```

On the underlying FS(HDFS, Local FS, S3-if you are using HBase on Amazon EMR).

Comment: OK, What i meant by separately is that, i was wondering if HBase can be used for storage alone. So, you are saying that HBase will not store any data but it takes HDFS to store the data? And HBase will contain the table structure? Then why is it called a database if it doesn't store data?

Comment: Hmm..Let me put it this way..Where do you sleep, your home or your bed room??Both are correct, right??Your bed room is nothing but a specific spot in your home used by you to sleep. It is just to make things more sophisticated, otherwise you would end up with just 4 walls and a roof where you would be doing everything, eating, sleeping, reading etc etc. You sleep in your bed room, but actually it is contained inside your home. Same holds true for databases. A database is nothing but an organized collection of data, like you have organized your home into bedroom, dining area, study etc etc.

Comment: And this is to provide you facilities like random reads/writes which HDFS, or any FS for that matter, lacks. You can go and fetch some particular data of interest without having to traverse through the entire dataset. Hope this answers you query :)